How to implement push notification for Flutter application through Microsoft Azure Notification Hub?
I want to use Microsoft Azure Notification hub for push notifications in my new Flutter mobile application but I didn't find any documentation or article on internet on how to implement it. Packages that are available on pub.dev for azure notification hub are not well documented I can't understad from them. I want to know that if we can implement it on Flutter or not? If yes then how can I implement it? Please tell me complete procedure for implementing it.
I used azure_notify_hub pakacge for imeplementing it:
import 'package:azure_notifications_test/fcm_service.dart';
import 'package:azure_notify_hub/azure_notify_hub.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FCMService.shared.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyAppAzure(),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppAzure extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppAzure({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppAzureState createState() => _MyAppAzureState();
}

class _MyAppAzureState extends State<MyAppAzure> {

  AzureNotificationhubsFlutter? _anh;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    _anh?.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("onMessage: $message");
          }
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              content: ListTile(
                title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
                subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('Ok'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message)async {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("onResume: $message");
          }
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message)async {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("onLaunch: $message");
          }
        },
        onToken: (String token)async {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("onToken: $token");
          }
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Running'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Hi @Huzaifa Zameer, Have you check this link.

Which package are they using for this
await AzureNotificationHub.connect(
connectionString: "your-connection-string",
notificationHubPath: "your-notification-hub-name",
listenForNotifications: true,
onMessage: (message) {
print("Received message: $message");
},
);
@SureshChikkam


I want to know that if we can implement it on Flutter or not? If yes then how can I implement it? Please tell me complete procedure for implementing it.

Yes, you can implement push notifications in the Flutter application using Microsoft Azure Notification Hub.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Initialize flutter_local_notifications plugin
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> selectNotification(String? payload) async {
  if (payload != null) {
    debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _showNotification(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _showNotification(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _showNotification(message);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    final String? title = message['notification']['title'];
    final String? body = message['notification']['body'];

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      title,
      body,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'item x',
    );
  }

  Future<void> _sendTestNotification() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('YOUR_AZURE_NOTIFICATION_HUB_SEND_ENDPOINT'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'YOUR_NOTIFICATION_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN',
      },
      body: <String, dynamic>{
        'data': <String, dynamic>{
          'title': 'Test Notification',
          'body': 'This is a test notification from Azure Notification Hub'
        },
        'notification': <String, dynamic>{
          'title': 'Test Notification',
          'body': 'This is a test notification from Azure Notification Hub'
        },
        'priority': 'high',
        'to': '/topics/all',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Test notification sent successfully');
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to send test notification');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Azure Notification Hub Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _sendTestNotification,
            child: const Text('Send Test Notification'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


The above code initializes Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications, configures the handling of incoming messages, and displays notifications when a message is received. Additionally, it includes a method _sendTestNotification() to send a test notification to all devices subscribed to the topic /topics/all.

Initially, create a test project in Firebase and enable messaging in the project

Here is my server key which need to add in the azure notification hub.

Place the API key, Project name, Client email as like below from firebase messaging.

Reference:

Send push notifications to Flutter apps using Azure Notification Hubs via a backend service.

flutterfire/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart at master · firebase/flutterfire · GitHub

Migration Guide | FlutterFire


